# .Net Events not firing outside of Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events, wmi

I have an app and one of it's functions is to check if Anti-Virus is running using WMI.

```
class AntiVirus
    {
        public delegate void AVStatusHandler(bool running);
        public event AVStatusHandler AVStatus;
        public delegate void AVStatusErrorHandler(string Error);
        public event AVStatusErrorHandler AVStatusError;
        public delegate void AVLogHandler(string Message);
        public event AVLogHandler AVLog;

        internal void GetAVStatus()
        {
            if (AVLog != null) AVLog("Getting AV Status");
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\Microsoft\\protectionManagement",
                    "SELECT * FROM MSFT_MpComputerStatus");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    if (AVStatus != null)
                    {
                      //  AVStatus("Anti-Spyware Enabled", (bool)queryObj["AntispywareEnabled"]);
                        AVStatus((bool)queryObj["AntivirusEnabled"]);
                     //   AVStatus("Behavior Monitor Enabled", (bool)queryObj["BehaviorMonitorEnabled"]);
                     //   AVStatus("Ioav Protection Enabled", (bool)queryObj["IoavProtectionEnabled"]);
                     //   AVStatus("NIS Enabled", (bool)queryObj["NISEnabled"]);
                     //   AVStatus("Real Time Protection Enabled", (bool)queryObj["RealTimeProtectionEnabled"]);
                    }
                }
                if (AVLog != null) AVLog("Getting AV Status - Completed");
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                if (AVLog != null) AVLog("Getting AV Status - Failed");
                if (AVStatusError != null)
                    AVStatusError("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

It raises the `AVStatus` event in the calling main form (`frmMain`)

```
 private void GetAvDetails()
        {
            av.AVStatus += av_AVStatus;
            av.GetAVStatus();           
        }

        void av_AVStatus(bool running)
        {
            SetRichTextBoxText(rtbConOut, "Av Status = " + running.ToString());
            Properties.Settings.Default.AntiVirusEnabled = running;
        }
```

Where the message is shown like this:
[image: Out put Example]
and the `Properties.Settings.Default.AntiVirusEnabled` is set to the boolean value of `running`.

When the mouse is moved to the top of the app a window is displayed showing various settings; where the `Properties.Settings.Default.AntiVirusEnabled` value is assigned to a `Checkbox.Checked` property. So if the AV is Running the `Checkbox` is checked.

[image: Checkbox Checked]

Everything works as it should within VS2013. However, when I publish this as a ClickOnce application and run it on a Virtual Machine (Hyper-V) the program does not raise the `AVStatus` event or update the `Checkbox` as can be seen here:

[image: Not Functioning Event]
[image: Not Checked Checkbox]

The Anti-Virus is running on both virtual machines.

So the question is:

Why does the code work properly on a Virtual Machine within Visual Studio but not on a virtual machine without Visual Studio?

Development VM = Win 8.1 Enterprise x64
Test VM = Win 8.1 Professional x64
Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you made sure that all files needed to run the program are included? If not, [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx).

Comment: Yeah - everything is there

Comment: My crystal ball says that you run Visual Studio elevated.  Running a ClickOnce app elevated is not possible afaik.

Comment: Sorry not running as Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event AVStatus is only triggered if there was at least one ManagementObject found. I would guess there is a right problem. Try to expand your logging and log the number of ManagementObject found, for example (AVLog is not used on the server?).